# Extracting 3rd digit of a hexadecimal number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to extract the 3rd digit of a hex number. For example, extract `4` from `0x4598`.

> To extract 0th digit: `(0x4598 & 0x0f) // returns 8`
>
> To extract 1st digit: `(0x4598 & 0xf0) >> 4 // returns 9`
>
> To extract 2nd digit: `(0x4598 & 0xf00) >> 8 // returns 5`

For the 3rd digit, I followed the pattern and tried `(0x4598 & 0xf000) >> 16`, but it returns `0`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern here would be to add four, not to double.

Try this instead:

```
(0x4598 & 0xf000) >> 12;
```